# problems with rand function in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to upload some images with php and I have a problem with the rand function and the database.
first I select an image and change her name (by adding some random numbers) befor moving it, after that I pick the new name with the directory and put it in th data base
this is the code of the upload

```
if (!empty($_FILES['profile-pic']['name'][0])) {
        $file = $_FILES['profile-pic'];
        $allowedExt = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
        $uploadsDirectory = 'resources/uploads/profiles/';
        $maxSize = 4000000;
        $upload = new Upload($file, $allowedExt, $uploadsDirectory, $maxSize);
        $uploadFile = $upload->uploadFiles();
        $data['profile_pic'] = $uploadsDirectory .  $upload->getFileUrl();
}
```

$data['profile_pic'] is the variable to put in the data base
the code of upload class is

```
/**
 * 
 */
class Upload {

private $files;
private $allowedExt;
private $uploadsDirrectory;
private $maxSize;
private $fileUrl;
private $filesName = array();
private $fileDimens = array();

function __construct($files, $allowedExt, $uploadsDirectory, $maxSize) {

    if (is_array($allowedExt) AND is_int($maxSize)) {
        $this->files = $files;
        $this->allowedExt = $allowedExt;
        $this->uploadsDirrectory = $uploadsDirectory;
        $this->maxSize = $maxSize;
    } else {
        echo "file extension must be an array and max size must be integer value";
    }
}

function uploadFiles() {

    $file = $this->files;
    $allowedExt = $this->allowedExt;
    $uploadsDir = $this->uploadsDirrectory;
    $maxSize = $this->maxSize;


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($file['name']); $i++) {
        $errors = array();
        $filename = $file['name'][$i];
        $fileex = explode('.', $filename);
        $extension = strtolower(array_pop($fileex));
        $size = $file['size'][$i];
        $tmpname = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

        if (in_array($extension, $allowedExt) === FALSE) {
            $errors[] = 'File extension not allowed';
        }

        if ($size > $maxSize) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less then ".$maxSize." KB';
        }

        if (empty($errors)) {
            $rand = rand(0, 9999);
            $this->fileUrl = $rand.date('d-m-Y') . $filename;
            $destination = ADMIN . $uploadsDir . $this->fileUrl;
            move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $destination);
            $this->filesName[] = $this->fileUrl;
        } else {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo $error . "<br />";
            }
        }
    } // end for loop
    return true;
}

// end function



function getFileUrl() {
    return $this->fileUrl;
}

function getFilesName() {
    return $this->filesName;
}

}

?>
```

the problem is that i heave tow different value from the rand one for the name in the folder and the other in the database, although when i echo the rand and the query just before the update  the value is the same 
value of the rand -> `9035`

name of the image in the folder `903529-01-2015_a.jpg`

the same value here -> `` UPDATE users SET `profile_pic` = 'resources/uploads/profiles/903529-01-2015-22-46-01_a.jpg' WHERE id = 13 ``

but in the database i have a different value 
for example:  `resources/uploads/profiles/14729-01-2015-22-46-01_a.jpg`

where is the problem ??

the table of users updated

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`adresse` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`telephone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`profile_pic` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT   'resources/uploads/profile.png',
`commentStatus` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`group` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Since you don't show your DB code, we can't really help you.

Comment: you mean the SQL code ??

Comment: well, you can also try to put a `time ()`, rather than `rand ()`, if it makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

U can  use `uniqid();` instead of `rand(min,max);` better solution or ad with `time();` a timestamp

;)
or count the fils by ur self:
if only numbred files in folder
$nextIndex = count(scandir(FOLDER))-1;

Comment: I used the uniqid() but the same problem the name was changed inside the DB although it was correct just before the update

Comment: do also str_pad() to make eg 6  to 0000006   for the index

Comment: u got the same uniqid();? if not its really a deeper problem of ur code that must be found

Comment: no not the same although when i echo the query that update the DB i have the same uniqid() but inside the DB the code change

Comment: If read ur code again and the big quest seems , from where comes id = 13

Comment: Is id an index of the table

Comment: Thing about insert instaed of update the table UPDATE only if name of the real file changes or DELETE if the real file is removed

Comment: 13 is the number of the profile thet I'm usign now, before the first code I get the information of the user by his cookie and the update his profile

Comment: yes id is the index, about the insert I don't think so if i have several users in the site and every time they change information of his profile I have than a huge table and information

Comment: But UserId and ImageID are some diff. things,  you save in the table for each image an unique entry, right? then use an unique image id  and the profile id     update   id = xx AND imdid = xx, thing about the logic behind it

Comment: Dont now from where the $_FILES comes and in what way, but i can see there is no image_id collect from there, so how u now ther deleted , inserted (or update) a new image, if i go completly the wrong way you have to post more logic code

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `adresse` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'resources/uploads/profile.png',
  `commentStatus` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `group` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

this is my table, I don't have a table for the images but in the table of users every user has an image

Comment: Ok, but the for loop above look like some can upload more images at once

Comment: name of the image in the folder 903529-01-2015_a.jpg

Comment: $this->filesName I used it in a different file, here where I had the problem I used just the $this->fileUrl